# Invoking REST API for making new component in JIRA

Tags: rest, httpclient, jira

I've to make a new Component in JIRA
I found out the **POST url  /rest/api/2/component**  for making new component, but i'm unable to know what type of inputs to be given.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/component/");

String authorization = JiraRequestResponseUtil.conversionForAuthorization();
postRequest.setHeader("Authorization", authorization);

StringEntity input = new StringEntity("\"name\":\"Component 1\",\"description\":\"This is a TEST JIRA component\" ,\"leadUserName\":\"fred\",\"assigneeType\":\"PROJECT_LEAD\",\"isAssigneeTypeValid\":\"false\",\"project\":\"TEST\"");

input.setContentType("application/json");
postRequest.setEntity(input);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

this is the code i'm implementing.

Output i'm getting is Failed : **HTTP error code : 400**

Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

we can't tell you. You need to find documentation on the service you are posting to.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is correct, just add the `{` & `}` to the JSON string.